# efficient and safe resource management

Tags: c++, architecture, resources

In my game I have a concept of resource manager, a class that stores and manages resources(fonts, textures, meshes, etc.). Very roughly it has following methods:

```
struct ResourceManager
{
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<T> GetResource(id_type id) const
{
    auto pRes = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T,Resource>(getResource(id));
    return pRes;
}

}
void load(); //loads resources from some storage
//etc.
};
```

Later, resources are acquired by some game objects, etc. So, obviously, Resource must be wrapped into shared_ptr. But what about internal data of Resource? Should it be also wrapped into shared_ptr?

For example, Mesh resource:

```
struct MeshResource : public Resource
{
std::vector<vertex>* vertices;
std::vector<unsigned int>* indexes;
};
```

Should be vertices and indexes wrapped into std::shared_ptr ? If yes - is there any alternative(idiom, or pattern, anything) to shared_ptr? It is very huge overhead, and I want to avoid using of shared_ptr in Resource subclasses. From the other side I want to protect data somehow. For example, following code must initiate compilation error.

```
delete pMeshResource->vertices;
```

Any ideas?

**The solution that I've came up with:**

```
struct MeshResource : public Resource
{
    const std::vector<unsigned int>& indexes() const;
    const std::vector<vertex>& get_vertices() const;
private:
    std::vector<vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indexes;
};
```

MeshResource is constant(asset) resource. It is impossible to modify it, but you can always read from it.

Comment: Why have vertices and indexes as pointers instead of by value?

Comment: because it is extremely inefficient to copy every time i want to acquire some resource.

Comment: @inncohenti That is why your resource is managed already? If there are really a lot of situations where different meshes share the same set of vertices, this is perfectly alright, but that depends on your application.

Comment: I'm not even sure you need the (expensive) shared pointers. If the resource manager actually manages the resource, you don't need *shared* ownership: The resource manager is the *sole* owner. Just hand out references.

Comment: @Kerrek SB Unfortunately, in that case I could not delete resources that are unused for long time.

Comment: @innochenti: Maybe - does the resource manager not store the resources itself?

Comment: then it will be very hard to manage resources. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only keep things that really need to be shared on the heap. Everything else should be on the stack. The difficult decision is what is to be shared and what not and this also depends on a lot on the actual use case.

If two meshes share there vertices and one is modified by some deformation, what should happen? Will the other also use the deformed vertices or do you implement copy-on-write to give each mesh it's separate set of vertices as soon as one is going to be modified?

Comment: Mesh vertices may be modified, but resource vertices is not. The same holds true for simple image, that can be used for texture. or even for font objects.

Comment: @innochenti Sorry, what is supposed to be the difference? By resource, do you mean the things that are in "storage" and by "mesh" vertices the ones that actually exist in the program?

Comment: think about resources as const objects.